# Why browser back button returns a blank page with the previous URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigation, react-navigation, react-router-dom

On pressing the browser `back button` why does an empty-blank page is displayed instead of the component that I'd visited before? Only the URL is getting changed to the previous one.
 Using React Router v5 

That is really frustrating, how can I fix this ?
SignUp.js

```js
 render() {
    return (
      <div className='signUp-div'>
        <Header />
        <Router history={history}>
          <div className='form-div'>
            <Redirect to='/signup/mobile' /> // Default page
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={'/signup/mobile'} component={MobileNum} />
              <Route exact path={'/signup/idnumber'}>
                <IdentNumber setPersonalID={this.props.setUserNumber} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path={'/signup/password'}>
                <CreatePass
                  setIfSignUp={this.props.setIfSignUp}
                />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

IdentNumber.js

```js
const IdentNumber = ({setPersonalID}) => {

  const handleCheckID = () => {
  history.push('/signup/password');
  }
 
  return (
    <div className='form-div'>
      <button              
        onChange={(event) => onChangeHandler(event)}       
      > Page password</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default IdentNumber;
```

Did I explain it right ?
Thanks

Comment: can you put these components in a codesandbox along with the imports? then we shall connect in chat.

Comment: @deechris27  Temporary please get this Link  - https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-cache-n0yun?file=/src/components/SignUp/CreatePassword.jsx

Comment: @deechris27 https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235085/discussion-between-extrasun-and-deechris27

Comment: @deechris27 I'm in the chat room now

Comment: I'm in the middle of something...need 30-40 min. I saw your app in codesandbox. I'm not able to visit any route other than /signup/mobile. /Home is protected, all routes redirect to /signup/mobile.

Comment: True, you need to pass the process. First enter mobile number, for example- 0520000000, ID number (example use) - 316187491, than password you choose. It has other issues at <Home> but thats for later, I’ll change it for now.

Comment: The blocker is, I'm not able to type anything from my keyboard, tried google translate for a password. Not able to paste as well. Hebrew detected.

Comment: @deechris27 Please refresh it ,I just removed all the hebrew, I'm in our chat room.

Comment: I think I found the issue. In your index.js can you change import { Router } from "react-router-dom"; to import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: Try and let me know, BTW I still see the Hebrew version of your app.

Comment: @deechris27 I see it too at the first refresh, than it change to English in a second

Comment: I'm certain BrowserRouter will fix your issue. Did you check?

Comment: @deechris27 Where to place `BrowserRouter` ? because I must use `  <Router history={history}>` in SignUp component, they can’t work together.

Comment: Wherever you're importing Router, just change the import to BrowserRouter as Router. Rest all shall remain same.

Comment: @deechris27 at `Index.js` and `SignUp.jsx`, Tried it right now, same issue!

Comment: @deechris27 updated `Index.js` and `SignUp.jsx` with `BrowserRouter as Router` same problem. You can check in the codesandbox. Router v5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235092/discussion-between-extrasun-and-deechris27).

Comment: @deechris27 `history` is in package-lock.json, its very frustrating, I have sevral issues with the routing . English only  - https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-bouman-y62sd?file=/components/Home

Comment: I understand. I'm trying to see how I can help to fix this.

Comment: can you check this. https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-pine-5uwoq
I tried many things and it's working now. I'm backtracking my changes to know what exactly caused it.

Comment: @deechris27 you mean you don't know what changes you did ? how can I trace them, I tried what you told me here and it look like the same at codesandbox. How can I download your files ? I copied SigUp and Index - no change same issue.

Comment: yup, just one additional thing. The main file where routes are defined needs to be enclosed in <BrowserRouter />, You did so, but there were 2 consecutive redirects. /signup and then from signup to /signup/mobile where the route is defined. This is where I felt perhaps HISTORY is getting lost. I put the /signup/mobile route definition in App.js and it worked fine.

Comment: @deechris27 Its not that path='/signup/mobile' that making it backwards, it was the `exact` keycode that made it not to come back to previous page, I don't know why. all those hours, days and I thought that without the `exact`  code it won't transfer pages

Comment: Since I changed many things. it became difficult to track when it worked. I commented out the route added in App yet works. Yes, you're right about the "exact".

Comment: We don't need "exact" key for all routes other than the default "/" when it is enclosed in switch and placed in the end. You had routes like /signup and /signup/mobile which at first made me think it's needed. But exact matches /signup and /signup/* as same. Switch renders only one route and whichever route is matched first. The order of route definition matters. Thats what made me think of moving MobileNum route from signup to App.js.

Comment: Thank you very much ! much appreciate. Elad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code sandbox link, I've observed a few things that could potentially cause this issue.

Update your imports from `import { Router } from "react-router-dom";`
to
`import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";`

`<BrowserRouter>` uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

The routes will remain the same. You're using react-router-dom v5.2.0, you could use `useHistory` to get the history object. `useHistory` simplified the process of making components route-aware.

With my changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-pine-5uwoq

We don't need `exact` key for all routes other than the default "/" when it is enclosed in `Switch` and placed in the **end**. But `exact` matches `/signup/mobile` and `/signup/*` as same. `Switch` **renders only one route and whichever route is matched first**.

[An example project](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts-unit-test-example-kmubx) for reference.

And if you want to handle the back button event yourself, follow the below examples.

In a function component, we can handle the back button press by listening to the history object.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Test = () => {

  const history = useHistory();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (history.action === "POP") {
        
      }
    };
  }, [history])
}
```

listen to history in `useEffect` to find out if the component is unmounted. `history.listen` lets us listen for changes to history.

**Example**:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Test = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    return history.listen(location => {
      if (history.action === 'POP') {
        
      }
    })
  }, [])
}
```

`react-router-dom` now has `Prompt`,

```
import {  Prompt } from "react-router-dom";

    <Prompt
       message={(location, action) => {
         if (action === 'POP') {
           // back button pressed
         }

       return location.pathname.startsWith("/test")
        ? true
        : `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}?`
     }}
     />
```

Comment: So which one to use ? and what am I suppose to get in those fucntions ? `onExit(nextState)` Sorry but I didn't understand.

Comment: let me explain in the answer.

Comment: Ok but I'm getting also  - `Cannot read property 'setRouteLeaveHook' of undefined`, and I did everything correct.

Comment: Your third function's condition ` if (history.action === 'POP') {` is true when pressing the back button , but how does it helps me?

Comment: When you navigate through the app, the routing is handled by React router, it gives you all methods needed. You would have something like history.goBack() for it. But the browser's back button is a browser event, on history.action === 'POP' you can do history.goBack().

Comment: Thank for your effort in answering me, but somehow these - `history.goBack()` , `history.go(-1)` just don't work   ;/ same problem... (inside `if (action === 'POP') { history.goBack(); }`

Comment: is this Route imported from react-router-dom or react-router?

Comment: also, try wrapping your component in Route with withRouter. like
<Route exact path={'/signup/mobile'} component={ withRouter(MobileNum) } />

Comment: I import only from react-router-dom. What about ‘CreatPass’ and ‘IndentNumber’ components, how can I wrap them?

Comment: export default withRouter(IdentNumber);

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue only when using history.replace() and not push.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235081/discussion-between-extrasun-and-deechris27).

Comment: `component={ withRouter(MobileNum) }` don't work, nothing works. With `history.replace()` the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235085/discussion-between-extrasun-and-deechris27).