# How to implement router leave guard like vue-router in react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, vue-router, react-router-dom

I need to ask user if submit form or not in react project like in vue-router beforeRouteLeave guard:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="name"
      v-model="name"
      placeholder="input some text"
    />
    <router-link to="/">go back or click goback menu in browser </router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { MessageBox } from "element-ui";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    http() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const isOk = Math.random() > 0.5;
          isOk && resolve({ ok: true });
          !isOk && reject(new Error("server 503"));
        }, 2000);
      });
    },
  },
  async beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    if (this.name) {
      // form has input
      try {
        // it's better to use UI modal than window.confirm
        await MessageBox.confirm("do u want to submit?", "tips", {
          confirmButtonText: "yes",
          cancelButtonText: "no",
          type: "warning",
        });
        const res = await this.http(); //submit form
        console.log(res);
        // http success,let it go
        res.ok && next();
      } catch (error) {
        next(false);
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

[demo in codesandbox online by vue-router](https://codesandbox.io/s/router-guard-when-back-8kofo?file=/src/components/MyForm.vue:0-1223)

This work well when user click goback and forward button in browser menu and Programmatic Navigation work as well. How can I implement the same requirement in react-router-dom?

I have tried this way based on [deechris27's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68541036/6524962), but it does not work as vue-router.

my key code :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Modal } from 'antd'
import { ExclamationCircleOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'

const { confirm } = Modal
function Confirm() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    confirm({
      title: 'Do you want to save data?',
      icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined />,
      onOk() {
        resolve({ ok: true })
      },
      onCancel() {
        reject(new Error('cancel'))
      },
    })
  })
}

function Users() {

  const http = () => {
    console.log("I'll show up on submit")
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ ok: true })
      }, 2000)
    })
  }

  const history = useHistory()
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')
  const changeInput = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.currentTarget
    setInput(value)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return history.listen(async (location, action) => {
      console.log(location, action)
      if (action === 'POP') {
        // const ok = window.confirm('do u want to submit form?')
        // url has change when confirm modal show
        try {
        await Confirm()
        // url has change when confirm modal Component show

        // send http request
        const res = await http()
        console.log(res)
       }catch (error) {
        // http error or cancel modal
      }
      }
    })
  }, [history])

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    console.log('**********')
    e.preventDefault()
    if (input) {
      // const ok = window.confirm('Do u want submit?')
      try {
        const { ok } = await Confirm()
        console.log(ok)
        if (ok) {
          console.log('send http')
          const res = await http() // answer is yet false
          console.log(res)
          res.ok && history.push('/')
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // http error or cancel modal
      }
    } else {
      history.push('/')
    }
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input name="name" value={input} onChange={changeInput} placeholder="input some text" />
      <br />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default Users
```

**When custom `Confirm Component` or `window.confirm` showed, the url has chenged, so this way can not stop navigate away. Prompt has the same issue.**

Answer (score 1):

You could do the same in React using `window.confirm`. Doing it the react way by using `state` value will have one problem; **timing** the 2 async actions: `setState` and your async function call based on the value of **answer**.

Example below:

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Test from "./Test";
import Leave from "./Leaving";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/prompt" component={Leave} />
      </Switch>
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Test.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Prompt, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Test() {

  const [answer, setIsAnswer] = useState(false);

  const history = useHistory();

  const http = () => {
    console.log("I'll show up on submit");
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ ok: true });
      }, 200);
    });
  };


  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    console.log("**********");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.reset();
    setIsAnswer(true);  // setting state is async
    history.push("/prompt");
    answer && (await http()); // answer is yet false
  };

  return (
    <div className="Test">
      <h1>Hello Jack</h1>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
          <Prompt when={true} message={(_) => "Do you want submit form?"} /> // **when**'s value should ideally depend on answer value, harcoded for example purpose.
        <button>Click</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Only when you click the second time, the React way of prompt is in action since `setIsAnswer` is async.

You could use the same `window.confirm` onSubmit.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    console.log("**********");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.reset();
    const answer = window.confirm("Do you want submit form?");
    answer && history.push("/prompt");
    answer && (await http());
  };
```

I created a working example for you here in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-dew-u32wx

In the above sandbox, `handleSubmit` is plain JS way. `handleSubmit2` is React way(click twice). Remove the commented `<Prompt .../>` inside the form and change `onSubmit` function to handleSubmit then handleSubmit2 to see both in action.

**Explanation**:

Any react module or approach that will rely on the **state** value will not help with your scenario, where you make HTTP call after prompt confirmation. `window.comfirm` is blocking code, using state for `answer` is non-blocking. If it's just about prompting before navigating away then you could go with the above react or any other react approach suggested.

**Update in response to comments:**

You could prevent the browser back button navigation by adding the below code.

```
const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (history.action === "POP") {
       return false;
      }
   };
 }, [history]);
```

**or** in your Prompt itself through callback

```
<Prompt
    when={(location, action) => {
      if (action === "POP") {
        //
      }
    }}
    message={(_) => "Are you sure, you want to go back?"}
/>
```

I've updated the Leaving.js in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-dew-u32wx) with this browser back button scenario.

Comment: I've updated my answer here and in codesanbox. I'd answered for the back button issue some days back. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68441641/why-browser-back-button-returns-a-blank-page-with-the-previous-url/68442116#68442116

Comment: I have upaded question, why my code does not work? can  not stop nav.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is to use a blocking flag. See this: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/preventing-transitions

Answer (score 0):

Either you can create this using react-router APIs or use an already available package like [React Navigation Prompt](https://github.com/ZacharyRSmith/react-router-navigation-prompt).

It uses react-router under the hood

Answer (score 0):

It's the simplest example to prevent a user to change the route by using the `react-router` and `react-router-dom` packages.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { Prompt } from "react-router";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [dirty, setDirty] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
       <input onChange={() => setDirty(true)} /> {dirty ? "dirty" : "clean"}
       <br />
       <NavLink to="/test">Leave</NavLink>
       <br />
       <Route path="/test" component={() => "Has left"} />
       <Prompt message="Are you sure you want to go to /test?" />
     </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

You just need to install these two packages `react-router` and `react-router-dom`. This is the simplest logic which is built like if your form is dirty then you should prompt the user and prevent them from the leaving the page.